# extra line inserted after <a href><img> with Bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Creating a grid of images from category tags, and using bootstrap css, I'm getting a large gap between the image (whatever size I use) and the title below. I'm not showing any other content.

The empty `<p>` that I would like to eliminate comes directly after the image:

```
<div class="col-md-4 pt-cv-content-item pt-cv-1-col">
<a class="_self" target="_self" href="http://example.com/post-one/">
<img class="pt-cv-thumbnail wp-post-image" height="150" width="150"  src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/image-46-150x150.jpg">
</a>
<p></p>
<h4 class="pt-cv-title">
<a class="_self" target="_self" href="http://example.com/post-one/">Post OneTitle</a>
</h4>
</div>
```

What would be inserting this line between my image and title?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv1g3qaf/1/)

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 pt-cv-content-item pt-cv-1-col">
<a class="_self" target="_self" href="http://example.com/post-one/">
<img class="pt-cv-thumbnail wp-post-image" height="150" width="150"  src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/image-46-150x150.jpg">
</a>


    
<h4 class="pt-cv-title">
<a class="_self" target="_self" href="http://example.com/post-one/">Post OneTitle</a>
</h4>

</div>
```

Comment: Sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: that doesn't work. What works is `.pt-cv-title p {display:none;}` but I'm trying to figure out what is generating an empty `<p>` tag above the title.